# In selenium, Not able to click on Error msg 'OK' button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

[image]

I'm trying to click on OK Button using selenium, cant find the elememt.

```
objBrowser.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'OK')]")).click();
```

OK button Inspect element code as below

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" jQuery15109548211953493255="16">

<span class="ui-button-text"> Text - OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` only selects text child nodes under the current context node (`button`). There is no text node that contains OK in `button`.

You need most likely:

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(span/text(), 'OK')]")
```

If the element is not immediately visible or clickable, you need to wait for it. This is usually done with a WebdriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 3); // 3 seconds at most
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(...));
```

Comment: @learner I've seen your answer, it is better to do this with a WebdriverWait instead of `Thread.sleep()`, because it will continue the execution as soon as the element is there. Thread.sleep() might break your test if the element needs longer than the static amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with cssSelector.

```
objBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("button:contains('Ok')")).click();
```

Comment: Got this Exception - NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == button:contains('OK')

Comment: looks like this is potentially related to the fact that `OK` is in uppercase. try: `objBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("button:contains('OK')")).click();`

Comment: yeah, probably. Try with uppercase. if it works I will edit the answer

Comment: `:contains()` is not a valid CSS selector. jQuery provides this.

Comment: Ok, then how could u explain sauce labs tips about :contains? [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Include it in your test code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
```

and after the action which opens the alert message

Try below code

```
Alert alert_test = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert_test.accept();
```

Let me know the error message in-case if it does not works.

For **Modal pop-up window**, Try below approach and verify.

Use below code after the action which opens the alert message

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

**Note:** *Some-times it takes few seconds to recognize the modal pop-up window present but some times it goes a bit long,so below time you can modify as per your need.*

```
Thread.sleep(7000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Actually its not Alert - Its a model popup window. Error is - org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is active

Comment: We have very few approach  to deal with modal boxes in selenium  and very few of them actually works in such cases, but yes we can handle them wisely. Can you tell me when you click on the action which opens this modal pop-up window where you find your cursor. Like if you click enter button on your keyboard manually then does it closes the modal pop-up box?

Comment: It works, Thanks . But the real problem was solved by other way. I have posted the way it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

@Rupesh and @Artjom B. Thanks

I checked and both of your answers are working.

But the real problem was at the button where error msg pops up.
so i added sleep before remove button on which popup occurs and this is working  with both of your answers.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
objBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[Value='Remove']")).click();

objBrowser.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(span/text(), 'OK')]")).click();
```